# Table won't stretch horizontally

Tags: html, css

I'm helping a company build a website in Wix and some basic functionality just aren't supported, such as tables and tabbed containers. So I had to write it in a module, and then I had to write an editor to make it easily changeable.

I'm sort of done with it but now I'm having the issue that the Table just won't stretch.

Here's the module, pretty much hardcoded and working perfectly fine:

https://alexandersopov.github.io/wix-table

And here's the editor:

https://alexandersopov.github.io/wix-table-module-editor

The CSS is pretty much identical and except for a few wrappers, the html is pretty identical (in fact, the only difference is that for some reason, a tbody tag gets added in the table in the editor, but I've tried giving that width:100% as well but with no luck).

So in the editor, there's a preview window where you can see the table under "specifikationer" and it's barely half of the width, even though inspecting it tells you it's suppose to be 100% (and indeed the inspector identifies it as such) and when I copy/paste the raw code into an empty .html document and check that out I get the same result.

I've been stuck at this for hours and can't for the life of me understand where this problem stems from.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] in your question. Linking to third party sites for the code is against the site's rules.

Comment: I added this [ row3,col1|row3,col2|row3,col3|row3,col4|row3,col5|row3,col6| ] to your definitions and the table stretched based on the number of columns I added.

Comment: @j08691

Thank you for the heads up, I wasn't aware of it. Is it cool if I keep op as is or should I change it? (I think I got a good answer below, will try it out)

Comment: @nocturns2 yes, that's correct but that's not my problem as I'd like it to stretch to 100% no matter the # of columns. I think I've found the solutions in the answer below, but thank you anyway <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table has the `.active-content` class applied, which changes its display type to `inline-block`. Try changing the class to something which sets it to `table` or `inline-table`.

Comment: Thank you, that solved it! I had no idea display had a table property.